# .net6 requiring fully qualified class name?

Tags: c#, class, .net-6.0

I have a solution (ConsoleApp6) with program.cs and Dog.cs in Visual Studio
In program.cs I am instantiating Dog.cs.
I've been a .net programmer for years, but am on day one of switching to .NET 6
in program.cs  "Dog" is not recognized (like it would have been in old .net) unless I qualify it with MyNameSpaceHere.Dog, even though it is the same exact namespace as program.cs.

```
ConsoleApp6.Dog dog = new ConsoleApp6.Dog(); //works

Dog dog = new Dog();  //does not
```

Error message says:Type or Namespace "Dog" could not be found. Even when I follow the fix and let VS create a new class Dog, it then doesn't recognize that.
Clearly I'm making some newbie error here???

Comment: What is the namespace where the line failing is located? If it is not ConsoleApp6 do you have the proper using statement?

Comment: Both are in the same namespace. I created a new project, then "added" a class to the solution.

Comment: They are not in the same namespace. When you "add a class to the project", it will honor your project's namespace, but your `Program.cs` does not by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a consequence of the ["top level statements" feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

Support was added so that you could "just code" without having to declare a namespace and a `Program` class with a `Main` method in it.

The consequence is that, everything that is in this "top level layer" is not part of any namespace, which means every reference to a class with a namespace will cause a full qualification *if you don't include the `using` at the top of the file*.

So the solution in your case is to just add the following at the top of your file:

```cs
using ConsoleApp6;

Dog dog = new Dog();  // works now
```

*Note: this is a C#9 feature and not a .NET6 feature.*

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I also discovered if I removed the namespace declaration in the added class that it would now be recognized without fully qualifying it. Thanks again!

Comment: @RNovey yep, you _can_ do top-level class declarations everywhere too, even though that is not necessarily considered a best practice. BTW, if the post resolved your issue, don't forget to mark it as the answer.